# Update sql table on logout

Tags: php, session, mysqli, logout

I want to update a table field on successful logout. But my code doesnt seem to work.

Below is my code. It destroys the session but it doesnt update the table field.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (session_destroy()) {
    include "lib/session.php";
    include "lib/mysql.php"; 
    $session_id = $_SESSION['grammarly_sessid'];
    $q=mysqli_query("update online_status set status='OFF' where id = '$session_id'");
} else {
    exit;
}

unset($_SESSION['grammarly_sessid']);
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location:../login.php')
?>
```

Please help.

Comment: hey, you need not use condition here as if(session_destroy()), when session_destroy is called it destroys complete session values, and there won't be use of the session variable, which you are calling within the condition $_SESSION['grammarly_sessid']

Comment: Ok. So what is the best format of my code?

Comment: and do not use session_start(); more than once in your script. this needs to be called before everything..

Comment: Actually, `session_destroy()` “**does not unset any of the global variables associated with the session, or unset the session cookie**” (see [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php))

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the session ID before you destroy the session.

You also need to pass the MySQLi identifier to the first parameter of the `mysqli_query()` function if you are not using it as an OOP object.

```
<?php
session_start();
$session_id = $_SESSION['grammarly_sessid'];

$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_pass');
mysqli_select_db($mysqli, 'database_name');

if(session_destroy())
{
include "lib/session.php";
include "lib/mysql.php"; 
$q=mysqli_query($mysqli, "update online_status set status='OFF' where id = '$session_id'");
}
 else{
exit;
}

header('location:../login.php')
?>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer. The problem is you aren't using the mysqli connection reference in the mysqli_query() function. To not have to use the $mysqli first parameter, you have to use mysql as an OOP object.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
include "lib/session.php";
include "lib/mysql.php"; 
$session_id = $_SESSION['grammarly_sessid'];
$q          = mysqli_query("update online_status set status='OFF' where id = '$session_id'");    
unset($_SESSION['grammarly_sessid']);
session_destroy();
header('location:../login.php');
```

here in this case, you don't have to add a condition..

Comment: try printing out your $session_id, does that print anything?

Comment: He is using mysqli_query() as a function, not as an OOP method, which  means he needs to pass the mysqli link identifier to the first parameter of the mysqli_query() function. See my updated answer.

Comment: yup, didn't check that 'i' in mysqli_. thats right @DanL